# Set focus on span tag using .focus()

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

The goal here is to focus on the result of a query after a search.
This because we want our website to be accessible, and the result read by a screen reader.

The result has the following structure:

```
<div class="result-container">
    <p>
        <span class="selected-solution" tabindex="-1" aria-live="polite">
            Text to be read
        </span>
        <button type="button" title="Delete selected solution">
            <span class="icon icon-close" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Delete selected solution</span>
        </button>
    </p>
</div>
```

I want to set focus on the span with class "selected-solution", using Jquery.
Because the "result-container" can contain other types of results (in case of no results, or internal error), I use a generic solution:

```
$selector.find(':focusable').first().focus();
```

But this solution is unable to focus on my previous span...
If I replace my span by a div, it works fine, but this is not a good solution here (it put the button on the next line).

If I try this command while running the website on local, I select my span.

Do you have any idea why the span cannot be focused on?

Thanks for your help!

**Edit:**

After further testing, it seems that the Jquery code works with the span **BUT** that the jasmine test associated fail with the criteria .toBeFocused() when using span.

Still strange, but another thing to explore.

Comment: I had the same problem (it was also due to a need to support Accessibility and set focus to a span, for screen readers).  My fix was tabindex=0.

    <span class="selected-solution" tabindex="0" aria-live="polite">
                Text to be read
            </span> 
 
This allowed focus for me.  However, I am fairly new to Accessibility support, so would this tabindex=0 interfere with Accessibility?

Comment: It won't mess with the order of this element. But it become focusable.
So a user going through your page with keyboard will stumble on it, could be a problem if you do not want it.
In my case, the problem was only with my jasmine test, the code worked fine on the page. So may be you can forget the test for this time and use tabindex=-1?

Answer (score 0):

tabindex attribute might be helpful, e.g. : `<span tabindex=0>Register</span>`

Answer (score -1):

`:focusable` is a **jQueryUI** selector, (not jQuery) - make sure to include jQueryUI.

Comment: jQueryUI is included.
Notably, the :focusable works when we use a div. Our problem is when using a span. :/